# elasticsearch offset and limit facets

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to make a search that both limits and "offsets" (the keyword from in elasticsearch) the facet result set, so something like:

```
'{
   "query" : {
       "nested" : {
           "_scope" : "my_scope",
           "path" : "related_award_vendors",
           "score_mode" : "avg",
           "query" : {
               "bool" : {
                   "must" : {
                       "text" : {"related_award_vendors.title" : "inc"}
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   },
   "facets" : {
       "facet1" : {
           "terms_stats" : {
               "key_field" : "related_award_vendors.django_id",
               "value_field" : "related_award_vendors.award_amount",
       "order":"term",
               "size": 5,
                "from":2
           },
           "scope" : "my_scope"        }
   }
}'
```

In the above, it returns id's 1,2,3,4,5 and if I remove "from" it still returns 1,2,3,5 in the result set.

The "size" is working correctly. In this case, it's returning five items in the result set.

My understanding is that solr can do this. Can this be done in elasticsearch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terms stats facet doesn't support the `from` parameter. The only way to achieve what you want is to set size to `size + offset` and ignore first `offset` entries on the client side. In your example it would mean to request 7 entries and ignore first 2.